# How to read more than 1024 bytes to x bytes in Netty

Tags: java, sockets, netty, socketchannel

I am new here. I have this issue with netty. Data is getting truncated when it exceeds 1024 bytes.
this issue arose when i ported from norm io Socket to Netty, using io i can read any data of x bytes like this TheClient is a separate thread that handles socket connection that has been accepted

public class TheClient extends Thread{

```
    private DataInputStream dis;
    private DataOutputStream dos;

  public TheClient(Socket s,SocketHandler sockHandler,SocketHandlerListener sockListener){        

     try{
          //open the streams to read and write data
            dis= new DataInputStream(this.s.getInputStream());
            dos=new DataOutputStream(this.s.getOutputStream());

          //this is how i read the data of any x bytes in server
            int len = dis.readInt();
            if(len >0){
            byte[]buffer = new byte[len];
            dis.readFully(buffer,0,buffer.length);
            String output = new String(buffer,0,buffer.length);
            CLIENT_REQUEST +=output;
            }
            //System.out.println("what i read: "+CLIENT_REQUEST);
       }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();   
     } 
   }
}
```

How do i read the same x bytes using netty without losing the data. I tried this

```
        public class NettyServer{

            public static void main(String []args){
               EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
                try{
                    ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
                    serverBootstrap.group(group);
                    serverBootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);//"localhost",
                    serverBootstrap.localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(Integer.valueOf(port)));
                    serverBootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
                            //pipeline.addLast(new HelloServerHandler2());
                            pipeline.addLast(new ClientHandler());      
                          }
                         });
                         ChannelFuture channelFuture = serverBootstrap.bind().sync();
                         channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
                      } catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     } finally {
                        group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
                    }
                 }
              }
            }
```

and then i have ClientHandler class where the read happens and where the data is truncated

```
   public class ClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

       public ClientHandler () {
            System.out.println("Preparing..."); 

       }

        @Override
        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
            ByteBuf inBuffer = (ByteBuf) msg;

            //supposed to read 100kb data or string   
            String received = inBuffer.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
            //but output has been truncated to 1kb or less
            System.out.println("Server received: " + received);

            ctx.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Hello : " + received, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
            System.out.println("done from server: " );
        }

        @Override
        public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
            ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER)
                    .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
            cause.printStackTrace();
            ctx.close();
        }
    }
```

I have searched and searched SO but none worked for me. How do i really read my full data in chunk until it is complete while appending to a StringBuffer or somethng... Please, help me. I am learning Netty and i am relatively new to java. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will beed to write your own decoder that will buffer the data until you receive everything. This is usually done by extending `ByteToMessageDecoder` and only put the `ByteBuf` to the `out` once it is complete.

Something like:

```
class MyDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) {
        if (in.readBytes() < expectedBytes) {
            return;
        }
        YourMessage message = decodeFromByteBuf(in);
        out.add(message);
    }
}
```